# Create bootable .iso file - from clonezilla made image folder

Tags: ubuntu, iso, clonezilla

My main goal is to save an existing !virtual machine! completely. To a bootable .iso file.
To make many other virtual machines from that original one >> Like you install Linux from an .iso

Google/Chat-GPT/Youtube is not my friend.

I managed to save the image of the virtual machine, with clonezilla to a folder. But no .ISO file anywhere

[this is the folder made by clonezilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhDNq.jpg)

I guess the .gz file named "ubuntu-vg-ubuntu-lv.ext4-ptcl-img.gz" is the file that i need. But im not sure. ( i need the other .gz files as well?

[the size of the .gz files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9EWA.jpg)

I tried to create an .ISO file with CloneZilla but I did not find any option for that. Even if I'm not in beginner mode.
I talked with chatGPT-google-Youtube but I don't see solutions for bootable .ISO

I may miss something.. .any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

clonezilla may can not create bootable iso file. i think that clonezilla just back drive to img file. You can try cubic : https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic